# Did not have + past participle sentences

Tags: grammaticality, past-perfect, past-participles

Usually we use "past perfect negative" as in "I had not eaten a burger when he arrived"

But could you pls tell me if we could also use "did not have plus past participle"?

As in "I did not have eaten the burger when he arrived" ( If yes then i guess did not have plus past partuciple sentences could stand on it's own with out adding other clause sentence unlike past perfect negative).

Comment: "I did not have eaten the burger when he arrived" does not sound right to me. I think it should be "I had not eaten the burger".

Comment: No, you can't use _did not have_ with a past participle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **did not** is the past. I **had not** is the past perfect. You can't combine the two together.

**I did not have eaten the burger when he arrived** is incorrect because you're trying to use both the past and the past perfect. It should be:

**I had not eaten the burger when he arrived.**

For the past, you might say:

I didn't eat the burger until [after] he arrived.